# Fire event from a service without "polluting" the $rootScope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I'm building an app in angularjs, where I have a central notification queue. Any controller can push into the queue and digest the messages.

I have built a service like:

```
angular.module('app').factory('notificationSvc', ['translateSvc', notification]);

function notification(translate) {
    var notificationQ = [];

    var service = {
        add: add,
        getAll: getAll
    };

    return service;

    function add(message, type) {
        notificationQ.push({
            message: message,
            type: type
        });
    }

    function getAll() {
        return notificationQ;
    }
}
```

(One of the problems with this is that the `notificationQ` can be modified unsafely by calling `svc.getAll()[3].message = "I have changed a message";` or something similar. I originally wanted a "push only" service with immutable messages, but this problem is outside of the scope of this question.)

If I digest this queue in a controller like:

```
$scope.notifications = svc.getAll();
$scope.current= 0; // currently visible in the panel
```

And use it like:

```
<div ng-repeat="notification in notifications" ng-show="$index == current">
    <p>{{notification.message}}</p>
</div>
```

I can bind to it, see it changing and all is well. I can cycle through past notifications by changing the variable `current`.

## The question:

When the queue gets a new element I want the `$scope.index` variable to change to `notifications.length - 1`. How do I do that?

I have seen examples using `$rootScope.$broadcast('notificationsChanged');` and `$scope.$on('notificationsChanged', function() { $scope.index = $scope.notifications.length - 1; });`, but I did not really like the pattern.

I have a controller that **knows** about the service, has a direct reference to it, and yet we use `$rootScope` to communicate? Everything else sees the `$rootScope`, and all the events from different services will clutter up there.

Can't I just put the event on the service instead? Something like `this.$broadcast('notificationsChanged')` in the service and `svc.$on('notificationsChanged', function() { ... });` in the controller.

Or would it be cleaner to watch the data directly? If yes, how? I don't like this as I was not planning on exposing the full array directly (I was planning on `get(index)` methods) it just sort of happened along the lines where I had no idea what I was doing and was happy that at least *something* works.

Comment: Instead of `this.$broadcast` and `svc.$on`, you could also just lets controllres register callbacks with the service, and call those callbacks directly in the service when things changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notification approach would definitely work. Depending on your implementation it would be the right solution.

Another approach would be to watch the notifications array in your controller, like this:

```
$scope.$watchCollection('notifications', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    $scope.index = newValue.length - 1;
});
```

This should work, because your controller receives a direct reference to the notifications array and therefore can watch it directly for changes.

As runTarm pointed out in the comments, you could also directly $watch the length of the array. If you're only interested in length changes this would be a more memory saving approach (since you don't need to watch the whole collection):

```
$scope.$watch('notifications.length', function (newLength) {
    $scope.index = newLength - 1;
});
```

Comment: It should be `$scope.$watchCollection('notifications', ..`, isn't it?

Comment: Actually, since only the length is needed, it can be simplified to just `$scope.$watch('notifications.length', function (newLength) {`.

Comment: good idea, this should save some memory if he is only interested in the length. I will put your suggestion in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could just manage events yourself. For example (untested):

```
function EventManager() {
    var subscribers = [];

    var service = {
        subscribe: subscribe;
        unsubscribe: unsubscribe;
        publish: publish
    }

    return service;

    function subscribe(f) {
        subscribers.push(f);
        return function() { unsubscribe(f); };
    }

    function unsubscribe(f) {
        var index = subscribers.indexOf(f);
        if (index > -1)
            subscribers.splice(index, 1);
    }

    function publish(e) {
        for (var i = 0; i < subscribers.length; i++) {
            subscribers[i](e);
        }
    }
}

function notification(translate) {
    var notificationQ = [];
    var addEvent = new EventManager();

    var service = {
        add: add,
        getAll: getAll,
        onAdded: addEvent.subscribe;
    };

    return service;

    function add(message, type) {
        var notification = {
            message: message,
            type: type
        };
        notificationQ.push(notification);
        addEvent.publish(notification);
    }

    function getAll() {
        return notificationQ;
    }
}
```

Then, from your controller:

```
...
var unsubscribe = notificationSvc.onAdded(function(n) { /* update */ });
```

Caveat: using this method the service will maintain a reference to the subscriber function that is passed to it using `subscribe`, so you have to manage the subscription using `$scope.$on('$destroy', unsubscribe)`